# How to execute a script at the start and end of every application?

Tags: logs, application

I am trying to log the applications that a user opens/closes.
Is there a way to execute a script (Java,Python,etc) everytime an application (like firefox) is opened and closed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wrapper, e.g. possibly called `firefox`, which can be found earlier in your `$PATH`. For instance:

```
#!/bin/sh
[commands executed before Firefox starts]
/usr/bin/firefox "$@"
[commands executed after Firefox quits]
```